# Azure Java function -502-Bad Gateway

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions

I have created Java azure function as given on following link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-java-maven

**Java Class:**

```
package com.khan;

import java.util.*;
import com.microsoft.azure.serverless.functions.annotation.*;
import com.microsoft.azure.serverless.functions.*;

/**
 * Azure Functions with HTTP Trigger.
 */
public class Function {
    /**
     * This function listens at endpoint "/api/hello". Two ways to invoke it using "curl" command in bash:
     * 1. curl -d "HTTP Body" {your host}/api/hello
     * 2. curl {your host}/api/hello?name=HTTP%20Query
     */
    @FunctionName("hello")
    public HttpResponseMessage<String> hello(
            @HttpTrigger(name = "req", methods = {"get", "post"}, authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS) HttpRequestMessage<Optional<String>> request,
            final ExecutionContext context) {
                
        context.getLogger().info("Java HTTP trigger processed a request.");

        // Parse query parameter
        String query = request.getQueryParameters().get("name");
        String name = request.getBody().orElse(query);

        if (name == null) {
            return request.createResponse(400, "Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body");
        } else {
            return request.createResponse(200, "Hello, " + name);
        }
                
    }
}
```

Function created and deployed successfully

[image]

Now when i try to access using curl

```
curl -w '\n' https://sundaydemo-20180526141357482.azurewebsites.net -d AzureFunctions

or postman 

https://sundaydemo-20180526141357482.azurewebsites.net/api/hello
```

Then get following error , I am wonder if anyone getting same error.

> 502-Bad Gateway
>
> The specified CGI application encountered an error and the server terminated the process.

**Logs :**

```
2018-05-31T02:02:50  Welcome, you are now connected to log-streaming service.
2018-05-31T02:03:50  No new trace in the past 1 min(s).
2018-05-31T02:04:50  No new trace in the past 2 min(s).
2018-05-31T02:05:50  No new trace in the past 3 min(s).
2018-05-31T02:06:50  No new trace in the past 4 min(s).
2018-05-31T02:07:50  No new trace in the past 5 min(s).
2018-05-31T02:08:50  No new trace in the past 6 min(s).
2018-05-31T02:09:17.161 [Information] Executing 'Functions.hello' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=b43d17c9-35c0-4c84-ab7e-26a8ec721fe9)
2018-05-31T02:10:50  No new trace in the past 1 min(s).
2018-05-31T02:11:50  No new trace in the past 2 min(s).
2018-05-31T02:12:50  No new trace in the past 3 min(s).
2018-05-31T02:13:50  No new trace in the past 4 min(s).
2018-05-31T02:14:17.183 [Error] Timeout value of 00:05:00 exceeded by function 'Functions.hello' (Id: 'b43d17c9-35c0-4c84-ab7e-26a8ec721fe9'). Initiating cancellation.
2018-05-31T02:14:17.451 [Error] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Timeout value of 00:05:00 was exceeded by function: Functions.hello.
2018-05-31T02:14:17.572 [Error] Executed 'Functions.hello' (Failed, Id=b43d17c9-35c0-4c84-ab7e-26a8ec721fe9)
2018-05-31T02:15:50  No new trace in the past 1 min(s).
2018-05-31T02:16:50  No new trace in the past 2 min(s).
2018-05-31T02:17:50  No new trace in the past 3 min(s).
2018-05-31T02:18:50  No new trace in the past 4 min(s).
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Also tried to remove all and added CORS *

[image]

**Storage :**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you got any progress with that?

Comment: This problem should be fixed by new mvn plugin, you can have a try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you met [Function Runtime 2.0 Preview Breaking Change](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/112).

On portal, function runtime has been updated to `2.0.11857.0`(Check your Function app settings panel). While maven plugin has not been updated to catch up.

So the code built by old mvn plugin is not compatible with latest runtime.

Workaround is to pin your function runtime to previous one. Go to Application settings panel and change `FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION` from `beta` to `2.0.11776-alpha`.

See this [issue discussion](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements-discussions/issues/50#issuecomment-396845065) for more details, new plugin is coming soon.

**Update-6/15**

New plugin has been released. See [notice for jave language worker](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/112#issue-327919928).

- Create new project using latest Maven Azure Functions Archetype

  ```
  mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=com.microsoft.azure -DarchetypeArtifactId=azure-functions-archetype
  ```
- Update existing project to use latest Azure Function mvn plugin

  1. function code(*.java)

     Before

     ```
     import com.microsoft.azure.serverless.functions.annotation.*;
     import com.microsoft.azure.serverless.functions.*;
     ```

     After(remove serverless)

     ```
     import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.*;
     import com.microsoft.azure.functions.*;
     ```
  2. pom.xml

     1)Before

     ```
     <dependency>
         <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
         <artifactId>azure-functions-java-core</artifactId>
         <version>1.0.0-beta-2/3</version>
     </dependency>
     ```

     After

     ```
     <dependency>
         <groupId>com.microsoft.azure.functions</groupId>
         <artifactId>azure-functions-java-library</artifactId>
         <version>1.0.0-beta-4</version>
     </dependency>
     ```

     2)Find one more `azure-functions-java-core` of `excludeArtifactIds`, change to `azure-functions-java-library`.

     3)Find `azure-functions-maven-plugin`,change version to `1.0.0-beta-2`.         See Latest version on [maven](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:com.microsoft.azure%20AND%20a:azure-functions-maven-plugin).

Comment: Thanks! Switching to azure-functions-java-library 1.0.0-beta-4 has made it work. But Functions do not work locally any longer. I've updated azure-functions-core-tools npm packages from 2.0.1-beta.28 to 2.0.1-beta.29, but it did not help. I already have .NET Core Runtime (v.2.1.0) installed.

Comment: @PavelS. If `don't work` means No job functions found, it's expected. Old mvn plugin doesn't generate `function.json` with `azure-functions-java-library`. Just wait for the new plugin. Or you can copy function folder(with function.json inside) to target.

Comment: @PavelS. New plugin is available.

Comment: Thanks after using new version its's working fine  on local  and azure