# Which class shall be decared for the incoming content of a azure function with Blob trigger in java

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions

I finished the java azure function tutorial. And want to build my azure function with Blob trigger instead of httptrigger.

```
public class Function {

@FunctionName("myfunction")
@StorageAccount("xxxxxxxxx")
public void blobHandler(
    @BlobTrigger(name = "content", path = "container/{name}", dataType = "binary") byte[] content,
    @BindingName("name") String name, final ExecutionContext context
) {
    context.getLogger().info("Java Blob trigger processed a request.");
    try {
        context.getLogger().info("Java Blob trigger function processed a blob. Name: " + name + "\n  Size: " + content.length + " Bytes");
        // process the CT converter function
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //TODO: handle exception
        context.getLogger().info("Error");
    }

}
}
```

And then when I figured out i should use Stream as datatype instead of Binary (dataType = "Stream") as in C#. However I could not find out which java class I should use for the stream datatype for the content. simply Stream class? Tried it, but it does not work for me. Does someone have more experience on that?

Comment: In the end, I successfully run the azure function in Java. As Jerry mentioned before, the run time version needs to be taken care of. Because of the breaking change, I need to update my azure-functions-java-core and then build the package again, deploy in the azure, Finally it workds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Stream` is not supported for now. See this [github issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-java-worker/issues/119#issuecomment-396428289).

[Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-java#data-types) says

> You are free to use all the data types in Java for the input and output data, including native types, customized Java types and specialized Azure types defined in azure-functions-java-core package.

For blobtrigger, we can use `String`, `byte[]`, POJO class for blobtrigger content binding. Note that when using POJO, parameter `dataType` must be omitted.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Good to know Stream is not supported yet. I want to get and parse my zip file via the blobtrigger. The file is normally ~5MB. Having tried with Byte[] with the binary type. It detects the incoming file, but it always run into timeout error, no matter how small the file is. POJO supports json format input, which is not very useful in my case.

Comment: @ZYJ Glad it helps. Test on my side, blobtrigger works fine with 5M zip files. Could you accept this answer and open another issue? You can provide more details like your function version and detailed error info.

Comment: Hi Jerry, you also used datatype as binary? and class type for content as Byte[]. It would be great, if you can share the brief code inside the function? Or is it the same from the template?

Comment: @ZYJ Yes, exactly the template in your question. dataType=binary, class type is byte[].

Comment: @ZYJ Did you run this function locally or online?

Comment: I run it online. checked the log from application log, still not running

Comment: @ZYJ that is the problem, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50615746/azure-java-function-502-bad-gateway/50831964#50831964).