# In azure function using JAVA, how to get request body

Tags: azure, azure-functions

In azure function using JAVA how to get request payload which is sent as json

My code is like this:

```
@FunctionName("hello")
    public HttpResponseMessage<String> hello(
            @HttpTrigger(name = "req", methods = {"post"}, authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS) HttpRequestMessage<Optional<String>> request,final ExecutionContext context) throws Exception {
        context.getLogger().info("Java HTTP trigger processed a request.");
        System.out.println("**********REQUEST BODY*************"+request.getBody());

        String cookie = new Authenticate().authenticateAndGetCookie();
        ExecuteCommands commandsExecutor = new ExecuteCommands(cookie);
        String s=commandsExecutor.control(request.toString());
        System.out.println(s);

        JSONObject jobj=new JSONObject(s);


        if (s == null) {
            return request.createResponse(400, "Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body");
        } else {
            return request.createResponse(200,jobj.toString());
        }
    }
```

Because of usage of HttpRequestMessage>, when I print the body on console as it is in code I pasted above, I am Getting this in console.

```
**********REQUEST BODY*************Optional[{
[13-06-2018 11:40:18] Java HTTP trigger processed a request.
[13-06-2018 11:40:18]   "Command": "com",
[13-06-2018 11:40:18]   "Id": "id",
[13-06-2018 11:40:18]   "Id2": "id2",
[13-06-2018 11:40:18]   "Operation": "op"
[13-06-2018 11:40:18] }]
```

But I passed below payload:

```
{
    "Command": "com",
     "Id": "id",
    "Id2": "id2",
    "Operation": "op"
     }
```

SO,I tried to use  HttpRequestMessage but I got the below exception

```
incompatible types: com.microsoft.azure.serverless.functions.HttpRequestMessage<java.util.Optional<java.lang.String>> cannot be converted to com.microsoft.azure.serverless.functions.HttpRequestMessage<java.lang.String>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you could just do

```java
String body = request.getBody().orElse("");
```

See a full example at [this article](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/azure-functions/functions-create-first-java-maven.md#windows-cmd).

Comment: For request.map it is asking for casting and if I cast it is showing Cannot cast from HttpRequestMessage<Optional<String>> to Optional<String>

Comment: thank you I already fixed this problem,but locally everything is working fine, but when I deployed it is not working. It is giving "The specified CGI application encountered an error and the server terminated the process". status code 502.

Comment: The log file is reading 2018-06-13T13:39:56.408 [Error] Timeout value of 00:05:00 exceeded by function 'Functions.hello' (Id: '7095b9a7-cfd2-4a8e-88e2-3f937066fad1'). Initiating cancellation.
2018-06-13T13:39:56.933 [Error] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Timeout value of 00:05:00 was exceeded by function: Functions.hello.

Comment: @vikram see whether [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50615746/azure-java-function-502-bad-gateway/50831964#50831964) helps.

Comment: Link is broken...